# (Python Numpy) ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (3,)

Tags: python, numpy

https://trinket.io/python3/278475119d

What does this error mean?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/f61d58dd874eadb8/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    print("Determinant of the matrix is : ",determinant_recursive(mat,N))
  File "/tmp/sessions/f61d58dd874eadb8/main.py", line 22, in determinant_recursive
    As[i] = As[i][0:fc] + As[i][fc+1:] 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (3,)
```

Comment: If `fc` is `0`, it will aim to elementwise add up `As[i][0:0]` (so an array that contains no elements) with `As[i][1:]` (so all elements except the first), since the two have not the same number of elemnts, it thus can not add up the items.

Comment: What's the `+` supposed to be doing here?  Is is adding (sum elements of) two arrays?  Joining two lists or strings?  The error implies you have arrays.   That kind of summation only works if the arrays have the same number of elements.